# Using "display:block" will cause the table to shrink on mobile screens, but without it, the table will enlarge the page width, what should I do?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have some `<table>` elements on a page. They work well on desktop.

However, on mobile screens, I have to set `display:block` to prevent it from enlarging the page width. But after that, the table shrinks and becomes ugly.

```css
table{margin:9px auto 0;font-size:11px;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%}
table td,table th{text-align:center;border: 1px solid #999;padding:5px}
table th{background:#ccc;color:#000}
table tr:nth-child(even){background-color:#f2f2f2}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>A: Very long Very long Very long Very long Very long Very long Very long Very long Very long Very long </th><th>B: Very long Very long Very long Very long Very long Very long </th><th>C</th><th>D</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td></tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
```

Here are the screenshots:

### When table content is simple:

[image]

### Fix by remove `display:block`

If I remove the display:block, it will be okay:

[image]

### Removal `display:block` caused new problem when content is rich

But if I remove it, the table will enlarge the screen if it's too wide, for instance:

[image]

### Have to add `display:block` back to prevent it, (bad loop)

Applying `display:block` to the table will make it work:

[image]

What I can do now is to specifically find the tables that might enlarge the screen and give it a special class. Is there any **general** way that I can make all my tables stretch the full screen when they're not too wide, and automatically apply the `overflow-x:auto` on it when they're too wide?

Update:

If the text is very long, it will be very weird. I want the table to overflow-x:auto on mobile pages, Wikipedia has the design I want. For example ([link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_(nominal))):

[image]

Looks like it has a `<section>` wrapped outside. It would be great if there should be some pseduo class like "::outside" or "::wrapper" in my case if I can't update the DOM.

Comment: Since you have not provided any code, have you tried display block with 100% width?

Comment: Yes I tried, both `min-width:100%` and `width:100%` - not working

Comment: Are you able to provide code so someone can troubleshoot? Also check if there is another codes that is causing this issue. By default a block element should span to full width.

Comment: Added, it's just raw table without much decorations.

Comment: try `table td,table th{text-align:center;border: 1px solid #999;padding:5px; width:25%;}` without `display:block;`. You have 4 columns in each example so that should do it. if you have dynamic columns then a class with required percentage will work.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add some codes.
table{table-layout:fixed;}
table td,
table th{word-break: break-all;}

```css
table{
  table-layout:fixed; 
  margin:9px auto 0;
  font-size:11px;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width:100%;  
}
table td,
table th{
  text-align:center;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding:5px;  
  word-break:break-all;
}
table th{
  background:#ccc;
  color:#000
}
table tr:nth-child(even){
  background-color:#f2f2f2
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA<th>B</th><th>C</th><th>D</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td></tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
```